# How to reference variable in method in FutureBuilder (builder:)?

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database, dart

I want to use the variable dbRef in inputData() in future Builder builder: you can see the variable in between asterisk .

```
void inputData() async {
        FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
        final uid = user.uid;
      final **dbRef** = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("Add Job Details").child(uid).child("Favorites");
      }

     @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return FutureBuilder (

            future: **dbRef**.once(),
            builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<DataSnapshot> snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                List<Map<dynamic, dynamic>> list = [];
                for (String key in snapshot.data.value.keys) {
                  list.add(snapshot.data.value[key]);
                }
```

Comment: You need to use a stateful widget. Use a global dbref variable in your class. When is your inputData() method called?

Comment: Actually i don't need the input method I created it to get the user id. For the userid i cant get it without a method. Now the problem is actually i want the current user id without any method so that i can access it in Widget.

Comment: I faced a similar problem once. I had to redo a lot of code. There are some ways to overcome the problem. One is to fetch the user / uid at the beginning of the app and save it in a static variable in a class perhaps (Not shared prefs as you will need a function to retrieve it again). This is assuming your uid never changes.

Comment: can you please give me an example in the form of code. I want the userid accessible through out the dart page

Comment: Sure. Give me some time, I will write a dart code and post the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one more approach to tackle the problem.

The idea is to use a variable _loading and set it to true initially.
Now, after in your inputData() function, you can set it to false once you get the dbref.
Store dbref, the way I stored _myFuture in the code below i.e., globally within the class.

Use your _loading variable to return a progress bar if its true else return FutureBuilder with your dbref.once() in place. Now, that you have loaded it, it should be available at this point.

```
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {

  // Is the future being loaded? 
  bool _loading;

  // This is the future we will be using in our FutureBuilder.
  // It is currently null and we will assign it in _loadMyFuture function.
  // Until assigned, we will keep the _loading variable as true.
  Future<String> _myFuture;

  // Load the _myFuture with the future we are going to use in FutureBuilder
  Future<void> _loadMyFuture() async {
    // Fake the wait for 2 seconds
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2));

    // Our fake future that will take 2 seconds to return "Hello"
    _myFuture = Future(() async {
      await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2));
      return "Hello";
    });
  }

  // We initialize stuff here. Remember, initState is called once in the beginning so hot-reload wont make flutter call it again
  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    _loading = true; // Start loading
    _loadMyFuture().then((x) => setState(() => _loading = false)); // Set loading = false when the future is loaded
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // If loading, show loading bar
    return _loading?_loader():FutureBuilder<String>(
      future: _myFuture,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if(!snapshot.hasData) return _loader(); // still loading but now it's due to the delay in _myFuture
        else return Text(snapshot.data);
      },
    );
  }

  // A simple loading widget
  Widget _loader() {
    return Container(
      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      width: 30,
      height: 30
    ); 
  }
}
```

Here is the output of this approach

[image: Output]

This does the job but, you might need to do it for every class where you require your uid.

========================================

Here is the approach I described in the comments.

```
// Create a User Manager like this
class UserManager {
  static String _uid;

  static String get uid => _uid;

  static Future<void> loadUID() async {
    // Your loading code
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5));
    _uid = '1234'; // Let's assign it directly for the sake of this example
  }
}
```

In your welcome screen:

```
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  bool _loading = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    UserManager.loadUID().then((x) => setState(() => _loading = false));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _loading ? _loader() : Text('Welcome User ${UserManager.uid}!');
  }

  // A simple loading widget
  Widget _loader() {
    return Container(child: CircularProgressIndicator(), width: 30, height: 30);
  }
}
```

The advantage of this method is that once you have loaded the uid, You can directly access it like this:

```
String uid = UserManager.uid;
```

thus eliminating use of futures.

Hope this helps!